# Can't compile Apk on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, compilation, project

I recently downloaded an Android project and I was modifying it. But when I want to compile it, it is impossible for me to do so. The project does not have "Gradle" and nothing appears on the Android tab. How can I solve that? Thank you

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello Jose, could you possibly share any error message you are receiving?  thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to create a new project and copy the desired files of existing project to the newly created project. it might be helpful.